# sessionFactory is null in Grails service

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have defined `def sessionFactory` in my class `class UpdateService.` However `sessionFactory` always remains `null`. (I am calling the service from a controller and a job)

I need to clear Hibernate second level query cache from that service. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you also use `def updateService` in the controller and job, or are you using `new UpdateService()`? You have to use dependency injection (i.e. `def foo`)

Comment: You are right! I am still a beginner to Grails and was using dependency injection wrong. I used new UpdateService in the controller and job. Please provide an answer so I can choose it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you also use `def updateService` in the controller and job, or are you using `new UpdateService()`? You have to use dependency injection (i.e. `def foo`).